# What UI mockup tools can be used to produce Eclipse UI "screenshots"?

Tags: eclipse, user-interface

What UI mockup tools exist that could be used to produce designs that look like Eclipse UI? Perhaps there is an Eclipse project available for this? (http://www.eclipse.org/projects/listofprojects.php doesn't make it easy to browse through all the projects and learn about them.) I would consider tools for any platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are wireframe sketches rather than Eclipse-UI like mockups, but I find http://wireframesketcher.com/ or http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/wireframesketcher very useful.

It's quick and easy to use, see the feature list here:
http://wireframesketcher.com/features.html

One thing they don't seem to mention there is their SWT Spy plugin which "allows you to convert your existing SWT UI into a wireframe that you can edit and revise afterwards" (their words from the help content of the wireframe sketcher feature).

They have a 14 day trial.

Comment: The SWT Spy plugin sounds very useful.

Comment: I've used it a bit, but not extensively, I'd definitely recommend getting the trial version and giving it ago. I also tried Balsamiq but find I can work faster WireframeSketcher, which is well integrated into Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up buying [SwordSoft Layout](http://www.swordsoft.idv.tw/) in the Mac OS X App Store. It's inexpensive ($6.99) and easy to use. While it doesn't have Eclipse-specific templates, it wasn't hard to create mockups that looked close enough to what I'm proposing.

Answer (score 1):

We use balsamiq [Balsamiq site](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups). You can use their web version for free. [Web version](http://builds.balsamiq.com/b/mockups-web-demo/)
However, the web version doesn't save. So you need to manually store the xml. Use export as xml and copy paste to a local file and use again import as xml to restart.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [ForeUI](http://www.foreui.com/), which can help creating UI mockup with various styles (Handdrawn, Wireframe, Windows xp, Mac OS X and Windows 7), and allows you to define behavior of your mockup then run HTML5 simulation in web browser.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, Eclipse has a project

http://eclipse.org/windowbuilder/

that actually can be used for constructing plugin mockups and to start off the plugin project through generating much of the UI stuff. Since it is an Eclipse project using all Eclipse artefacts as they show in Eclipse, there's probably no better tool at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MockupUI](http://mockupui.com/). It is a desktop user interface mockup software. Not using Eclipse, but it lets you draw high fidelity UI screens with a native Windows 7,8 or 10 look and feel.